# AWS KMS Support for PGP encryption

Tags: spring-boot, bouncycastle, jce, amazon-kms

I have a batch process that require PGP encryption for files before writing them to "Archive" location.

I read a little about PGP encryption using Java and learned that Bounsycastle does provide that capability. However it does require a Public/Privake key for PGP.

My question is - Can I use RSA key generated by Amazon Web Services(AWS) KMS for PGP encryption? Or Do I need to use PGP key generated by GnuPG to use for PGP encryption? I can use GnuPG as well for key generation, however we are using AWS infrastructure, so i am curious if we can use the Asymmetric Key(RSA) generated by AWS KMS and use that with BouncyCastle for PGP encryption.